# Install SP2016 on-premise hanging

Tags: 2016, installation

We are installing SP2016 on-premise on single server (Win2016 std). After installed the prerequisites, I install the binary. Now it is hanging as the screenshot. Press the cross at right top corner have no respond.

Our server is not Internet connected. Is the program try to connect to Microsoft server?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The installer does not require internet connection to complete. You might want to check Windows Eventlog or Setup log.

> If Setup fails, check log files in the Temp folder of the user account that you used to run Setup. Ensure that you are logged in using the same user account, and then type %temp% in the location bar in Windows Explorer. If the path in Windows Explorer resolves to a location that ends in a "1" or "2", you will have to navigate up one level to view the log files. The log file name is SharePoint Server Setup ().

[Install SharePoint on a single server with a built-in database](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/6e2bcaab-58d3-47cb-b97e-34548732dfb8(v=office.16).aspx)